# Error setting parameters jdbi call

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm getting this error:
UnableToExecuteStatementException: Unable to execute, no named parameter matches "nroCotizacion" and no positional param for place 0 (which is 1 in the JDBC 'start at 1' scheme) has been set ...

the code is:

```
Handle h = null;
    try{
        h = dbi.open();
        String stmt = "{call pkg.test_procedure(:nroCotizacion,:ramo,:tipoVista,:planes)}";

        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) h.createCall(stmt)
                .bind("p_nuCotizacion", nroCotizacion)
                .bind("p_ramo", ramo)
                .bind("p_tipoVista",tipoVista)
                .bind("p_subproducto",planes)
                .registerOutParameter("v_titulos", OracleTypes.CURSOR)
                .registerOutParameter("v_datos", OracleTypes.CURSOR)
                .invoke();

        List<TituloCoberturaBeneficioTO> titulos = new ArrayList<TituloCoberturaBeneficioTO>();
        ResultSet rs2 = (ResultSet)rs.getObject("v_titulos");
        while(rs2.next()){  ......
```

i don´t know what is wrong, i'm new with jdbi.

Answer (score 0):

Your binding parameter names have to match the parameter list in the statement.  Eg:

```
ResultSet rs = ...
...
.bind("nroCotizacion", nroCotizacion)
...
```

Remove the `p_` prefix from your binding parameter names, or modify the statement to use the `p_` prefix.

Comment: but the parameter in the statment should be the nroCotizacion or "p_nuCotizacion" ?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my answer originally.  It doesn't matter which ID you use, as long as it matches in the statement and when you bind your variables in the `bind` call.  As it stands now:

`:nroCotizacion` is in the statement but
`p_nuCotizacion` is in the bind.

Comment: thanks thats ok. Now I have this error : SQLException: invalid column type for p_subproducto in java is a String[] and y my db is xmltype. how can i set this?

Comment: What's your db schema look like?

Comment: i don't know what you mean. it's a oracle 9i db